# How to apply NSSortdiscriptor or NSPredicate on a NSSet of a to-many relationship

Tags: swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort or filter the objects returned by a fetch request that are within a `NSSet` (from a to-many relationship). Here `routineSplitsRel` is a `NSSet` of `RoutineSplits` which should be returned in "displayOrder". Applying the `sortdescriptor1` returns an error saying:

> 'to-many key not allowed here'

```
class Routines: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var id: NSNumber
@NSManaged var isdeleted: NSNumber
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var repetitions: String
@NSManaged var uid: String
@NSManaged var updatedat: NSDate
@NSManaged var displayOrder: NSNumber
@NSManaged var trainingdayRel: NSSet
@NSManaged var exercisesRel: NSSet
@NSManaged var routineSplitsRel: NSSet

}

class RoutineSplits: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var id: NSNumber
@NSManaged var uid: String
@NSManaged var displayOrder: NSNumber
@NSManaged var isdeleted: NSNumber
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var routinesRel: myTP.Routines

}
```

FetchRequest:

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Routines")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "displayOrder", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "routineSplitsRel.displayOrder", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isdeleted == %@",NSNumber(bool: false))
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort directly a to-many relationship.
You need to fetch them and after you can sort them.
When you get your NSSet you can "convert" it to Array by using `mySet.allObjects()`

So it will be something like that

```
fetchResults.allObjects.sort({ $0.displayOrder.integerValue > $1.displayOrder.integerValue })
```

Comment: a little correction: it does not work like this  if displayOrder is a NSNumber. solution: ({ $0.nummer.integerValue > $1.nummer.integerValue })